# Is it possible to choose six triples of lengths from $1,2,3,\ldots, 20$ to form six triangles with equal perimeters?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangle-inequality

> Rachael has 20 thin rods whose lengths, in centimeters, are $1, 2, 3, \ldots, 20$. Any two rods can be connected at their ends. Rachael selects three rods to make a triangle, then three other rods to make a second triangle, and so on.
>
> However, Rachael wants to use 18 rods to form a set of six triangles with equal perimeters. Either find such a set, or explain why no such set exists.

**So here are my thoughts on this problem:**
I know that the $1\mathrm cm$ rod is unusable  because of triangle inequality. Now I am remained with $2 \mathrm cm, 3 \mathrm cm, 4 \mathrm cm, \ldots, 20 \mathrm cm$ rods, but this is still 19 rods. So my initial thought is to go through all the different possibilities and see if such set exist but I feel like this will be too time consuming. I am just wondering if there are a more time efficient method to determining if such set exist.

Comment: The triangles must all have the same perimeter.  What is that perimeter?

Comment: @saulspatz the question did not give the perimeter, that is the tricky part. There a few combinations but i can never get a set of 6 triangles with the 18 sides.

Comment: I meant that you have to figure out the perimeter.  Have you done that?

Comment: @saulspatz they are different perimeters, I found 3 sets of triangles for perimeter of 24cm, 3 sets of triangles for perimeter of 25cm. There are so many possible combinations of perimeters but I just can not seem to find 6 sets of triangles of the same perimeter. I am starting to think it is impossible but I can not put in into a logical mathematical reasoning.

Comment: Did you look at the answer I posted?

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the integers from $1$ to $20$ is $210$, and $210/6=35$.  Since we only use $18$ of the $20$ rods, the perimeter of the triangles must be less than $35$, so it's $34$ at most.  We discard $2$ of the rods, but we must use one of length at least $18$, so there is a triangle whose longest side is at least $18$ and whose perimeter is at most $34$.  This is absurd, so the problem is impossible.

Comment: I just have one question, why do we need one of the length of at least 18?

Comment: @01010101 Because you have 20 rods, and since you are using 18 of them, you can only discard 2 of them.  assuming that you discard the rods of length 20 and 19, that still leaves the rod of length 18, that must be used.

Comment: @user2661923 can i not discard the rod length 18? Because I know 1 must be discarded, but the second rod can be 18 as well? That is what I am confused about.

Comment: Of the 3 rods 18,19,20, at least one must be kept.  Therefore, there will be at least 1 rod, whose length is $\geq 18.$

Comment: @user2661923 sorry to ask again, but I am not entirely sure which rod to discard. Why did we look at $18, 19, 20$. Does this have something to do with the perimeter of the triangle being 34cm at most? If so, how does the rod $18, 19, 20$ play a part in this. Because the part I am really confused at is that we need 18 rods only, in theory we can discard any two rods where the$1cm$ must be one of the discarded rods.

Comment: saul spatz' answer demonstrates that a contradiction exists if one of the rods is **at least** 18 in length.  The point of my comments is that since at least one of the 3 rods, 18,19,20, must be kept, you know that one of the rods to be used **must be at least** 18.  Therefore, the contradiction demonstrated in saul spatz' answer stands.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the 19 rod lengths is 209. Even if we throw out the rod of length 20 (to make a set of 18 rods), the perimeter must be at least 2(19)+1 = 39. Six triangles with that perimeter would require a total rod length of 6(3) = 234. The total length of rods is insufficient to make the required triangles.